# error on creating spring Embedded kafka instance

Tags: apache-kafka, broker, spring-kafka

This is related to embedded kafka server provided by spring. On running my test case, embedded kafka intantiation (as show below) fails.

public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, KAFKA_TOPIC);

instantiation fails with following error.

1> C:\Users\r2dev\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-1587343850239557903\version-2\log.1: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

2> C:\Users\r2dev\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-7315008084340411800.lock: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I am using "1.2.0.RELEASE" spring kafka version and Java 8.

Any one faced this issue and were able to fix this issue. Please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show, please, more code of that test-case (or maybe whole) and more stack trace. Now it's not so obvious, sorry

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. Have you found a solution?